# Can grub2 chainloader a efi application on a filesystem other than FAT32?

Tags: grub2, uefi

I have a efi application in XFS partition. `(hd0,gpt2)/test/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI` I try to chainloader it by:

```
set root="(hd0,gpt2)/test"
chainloader /EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI
```

But chainloader failed with cannot find (hd0,gpt2)/test. Does this means the efi need to reside on a FAT32 partition? Or there is some mod I missed?

I did some research via grub2 shell. It looks like I cannot set path as root. When I do `ls /` it said `disk (hd0,gpt2)/test` not found. Does this mean the root can only be a disk partition?